# What types of non-linearities can GEKKO handle?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I've been using GEKKO successfully for a variety of problems but one thing I haven't been able to pin down is what the limits are in terms of non-linear terms in objective functions or constraints. I've found that some non-linear terms are tolerated, e.g.

```
m.Obj(sum(x * values) / sum(x))
```

seems to work fine, however

```
m.Obj(sum(x * values + x ** 2 * other_values) / sum(x))
```

seems to be unsolvable. Is there any documentation about the limits of GEKKO to handle certain forms of non-linearities that might help me reformat my problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Model building functions](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html) are listed in the Gekko documentation and include any nonlinear function that can be mathematically expressed with continuous first and second derivatives. Gekko gives the problem to a solver to attempt a solution. Sometimes the solver (`IPOPT`, `BPOPT`, `APOPT`) identifies the problem as infeasible or fails to find a solution. This doesn't mean that Gekko can't use these functions, only that a numerical solution was not found. You can try switching solvers with `m.options.SOLVER=1`. You may also need to use more efficient versions of the functions such as the Gekko `m.sum()` instead of the Python `sum()` function.

```py
m.Minimize(m.sum(x * values + x ** 2 * other_values) / m.sum(x))
```

Certain solvers such as a `APOPT` also allow mixed integer problems. Differential and algebraic equations are also solvable with Gekko. There is more information in the documentation on [switching solving modes with IMODE](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/global.html?highlight=imode#imode). There is a preview of applications with the [18 example applications](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization).